# Do subsurface modifiers need to be applied if an image texture is used as an object's materials?

Tags: modifiers, texture-baking

My guess is yes, but there may be a better way to do this so I'm asking. 
I have been trying to bake the appearance of rendered objects onto their materials like [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO5hnFXzXvQ&list=PLsPXv7sL0venQkWj1X4D_I-IzHW5o7JFT&index=8), which adds a bit about how to then export such models to Sketchfab. The baked textures follow the lines of the object as though subsurf has been applied. Is this a case where you have to apply the modifier?

[image]

Comment: If you dont want to apply the subsurf modifier try to disable subdivide UVs on the modifier and bake the texture.

Comment: @Denis somehow i missed the notice of your comment - and now i have applied the subsurfs and retopologized to minimized faces on those parts, so i'll have to try that another time :] I do note that the texture turned out fine on another object with a subsurf, so there must be things to consider about shape.